# With HTML and CSS, how to have an image that is vertically aligned with a horizontal line?

Tags: html, css, alignment, line

I'd like the image on the left to be adjacent to the horizontal line on the right (bottoms lining up flush).  It should be responsive so that the line can change widths as needed.  Right now, the image is sitting on top of the line, not beside it.

Edit:  This will give more clarification. The orange piece is an image.  The thin grey line is the line.   http://screencast.com/t/beMBRhpBpZ

Here is the HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png">
    <hr>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
img {
    float:left
}
hr {
    width:100%
}
```

How to make this happen? The HTML/CSS can be changed as required.  But should be cross-browser compatible and responsive.

Comment: Does the image have a fixed width?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish a border on the bottom? If that's the case just use `border-bottom`. Please clarify.

Comment: @bfrohs Not sure what you mean (I'm new to this).  The image's width is its native width.  I'm not changing it in the HTML or CSS.

Comment: @mikhailvs See above as I added a link to explain more visually.

Comment: as mikhailvs said, we dont need hr. you just need to apply border bottom to div http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -3px;
}
```

you dont really need hr. border-bottom is what you needed.

Comment: Yes, this worked thanks!  The left side of the image image is a bit transparent (1px wide) so the line can be seen on the left side.  As a work around, I made the divs left margin -1px.